# Where to set Visual studio 2013 property macros

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm a new VS user.

I've received some sample C++ projects working with a 3rd party API. They were saved in VS2012 format, but I have VS 2013. After conversion I find that there is an API specific macro defined in the project properties in the "Linker|General|Additional Library Directories" category.

If I click on 'edit' I can replace the macro with an actual path, but how do I establish what the macro points to?

In other words, how does one create a macro usable in multiple projects?